# In HighCharts column time series chart, crosshair not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

Thanks in an advance.

I tried to apply crosshair on xAxis, but its display very thin gray background line on each column. I want to display crosshair on xAxis group wise. Need this behavior in Column and Bar time chart.

Prepared [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdevft1b/).

Working with normal column charts [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsubwd68/8/)

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: "column",
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      format: "{value:%b %e}"
    },
    tickInterval: 604800000,
    type: "datetime",
    min: 1569888000000, // 2019-10-01T00.00.00.000Z
    tickPositioner: function() {
      this.tickPositions[0] = 1569888000000; // 2019-10-01T00.00.00.000Z
      return this.tickPositions;
    },
    crosshair: true
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
      x: 1569888000000, // 2019-10-01T00.00.00.000Z
      y: 952,
    }, {
      x: 1570492800000,
      y: 1082,
    }, {
      x: 1571097600000,
      y: 856,
    }, {
      x: 1571702400000,
      y: 1264,
    }, {
      x: 1572307200000,
      y: 1004,
    }, {
      x: 1572912000000,
      y: 1121,
    }],
  }]
});
```

So want to display gray background completely covered column.

In below images, you can see I got yellow highlighted gray shadow with thin line, but I need result like in next images. So there is only changes in structure I am using column time series chart in that case gray shadow not showing properly. For other column charts gray shadow display properly.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the `datetime` axis type, it is necessary to override the Highcharts function to achieve this:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'drawCrosshair', function(proceed, e, point) {
    proceed.apply(this, e, point);

    if (this.isXAxis) {
      const points = this.series[0].points,
        length = points[1].plotX - points[0].plotX;

      if (this.dateTime) {
        this.cross.attr({
          stroke: H.Color.parse("#ccd3ff").setOpacity(0.25).get(),
          'stroke-width': length
        });
      }     
    }
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lj3kgen0/

**Reference:**
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=50829

Comment: yes I tested its working with if single column in time series. But its not working with group of column in xAxis. i.e. https://jsfiddle.net/zyrjg13n/2/
Basically in this example I need to display gray background with group of columns in particular time period.

Comment: In your example, the series[0] doesn't have enough number of points and returns errors. You can use instead the second series ` const points = this.series[2].points,
        length = points[1].plotX - points[0].plotX;` https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/49j8ckrL/

Comment: Is it possible for bar time chart?

Comment: Sure: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sy1qfzd5/ (Just swap points: `length = points[0].plotX - points[1].plotX;`)

Comment: This example (https://jsfiddle.net/cy3eL8gq/7/) getting length value 'NaN'... this is also column time chart... And also bar time (https://jsfiddle.net/7htec5v0/3/)

Comment: This is the same situation as in previous ones - you need to have the longer array of points (in your example you try to use points[1].plotX but it doesnt exists - ther must be minum 2 data in the series you reffer to), like eg. here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t2d9gqm7/

Comment: sometime I got more length value for crosshair. So its take more area for crosshair. See in this example https://jsfiddle.net/7d18o5ku/3/

Comment: I see. Try to use `xAxis.minPixelPadding *2` instead. I tested it with a few of your use cases and seems to be more universal choice https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mxcafds5/ . Let me know if this works for you